# Why wash_out can't use identical data types in different soap actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, wash-out

I use wash_out from the master branch.
Why I can't use identical data types in different soap actions?

Sample:

```
soap_action "get_groups",
:args   => {:page => :integer},
:return => {:data => [{:id => :integer, :name => :string}], :total => :integer}

soap_action "get_items",
:args   => {:page => :integer},
:return => {:data => [{:id => :integer, :name => :string}], :total => :integer}
```

Also I tried wrap it in WashOut::Type but it not help.

Error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Duplicate use of `data` type name. Consider using classified types.)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't use identical data types"? Can you include the error that you're getting?

Comment: I'm added an error message in the question text.

Comment: Shouldn't `{:id => integer, :name => :string}` be `{:id => :integer, :name => :string}`? Notice `:integer` and not `integer`.

Comment: This is only a typo in a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for myself. 
WashOut can't work with nested objects.

Every hash must be replaced with WashOut::Type. 
It should look like this: 
    {:data => [SomeType], :total => :integer}